# Postal address verification in oracle apex

Tags: oracle-apex

I need to validate postal address in oracle apex. I did see this document on restful API verification provided by Oracle.
https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/address-verify-cloud/csads/index.html#CSADS-GUID-7B8F5D5E-530A-4DFE-B5FE-7003490232DE

However I am not sure how to use it within oracle apex. Any other pointers on how to achieve  this? Basically I want to ensure that a street address is standard example N Harrison St and not North Harrison Street / etc.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some suggestions on how to access restful services in APEX. Google each of them: there are plenty of blogs available.

- Check out "Web Source Modules". Apex allows you to create a data source on top of a restful service.
- There also is the `APEX_EXEC` api that allows you to expose restful services in pl/sql.
- or do it the old fashioned way using `APEX_WEB_SERVICE` api to invoke the restful service. You'll have more work if you choose to do it this way since you manually need to parse the response.